# VirtualBox and VMware are crashing in my computer

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, vmware, windows-8.1, virtualization

I am trying to install VirtualBox or VMware in my Windows 8.1 PC but I encounter various problems.
VirtualBox freezes my PC when installing it and I have to reboot.
VMware froze my PC once or twice but I managed to install it. I even manage to install a Debian image, which run once, but when I rebooted the guest OS it kept crashing.

It seems that it is not program specific, but there is a general problem with virtualization and my PC.

Details:

- I am using the latest versions for both programs (VirtualBox: 4.3.12, also tried 4.3.10, VMware-player-6.0.2)
- I installed VirtualBox some months ago, but for irrelevant reasons I uninstalled it. At that time, it worked perfectly (although I had the subjective feeling that it made my network adapters slower).
- I ran `chkdsk` on my SSD where Windows and the virtualization software is installed and it's OK.
- I tried closing any processes that can be ended running in Windows and tried both software. It allowed me for some reason to install VirtualBox, but it still crashes when trying to install an image.

Specs:

- CPU: i7 4770K CPU (virtualization enabled in BIOS)
- mobo: ASUS Z87 deluxe
- RAM: 2x8 GB DDR3

Comment: Please provide specicfic hardware information so we can verify your hardware supports the virtualization technology you want to use. Provide information on the actual crash otherwise we can't help.  Please provide specific version numbers for both VMWare and VirtualBox.

Comment: I addded more details about my PC specs, and software version. About the crash there is not much to say, the PC freezes and I have to reboot in the case of VirtualBox. When trying VMware I get different errors every time: either I cannot take ownership of my suspended guest OS, or I won't be allowed to install. Unfortunately, I uninstalled them and dont remember much detail but I can try to simulate the whole experience again...

Comment: What do you mean the system freezes? Are you waiting long enough, when a host operating systme freezes, that sounds like a I/O problem. What do you mean you can't take ownership of the the suspended guest operating system be specific.  I thought the computer was crashing, the host os freezing, is an entirely different problem then a host operating system crashing.

Comment: Sorry if I seem vague. When I say it freezes, it stalls completely (always at the same point of the progress bar). I left it for more than 30 minutes and it did not continue. Maybe it would be better if I repeat my steps and I provide more details, in order to not waste your time.

Comment: don't worry about wasting peoples' time, it's for them to decide how they spend their time.  An OS can crash and freeze(as in, even clock stopping - happened to me a few times on XP) but I don't know if you are describing that. Check event viewer to see if there's any info in the log. e.g. Win7 has an application log, and a log for system events.. and you could look for red Xs.. I don't have Win8 but no doubt it has similar

Comment: I am experiencing what may be a related problem. Windows 8.1 Pro with all updates. Core i3-3220, ASUS P8H61 M/LE/CSM mobo. Updated UEFI f/w with VT enabled. 8 GB DDR3 RAM. VirtualBox 4.3.12. If I leave 64-bit CentOS 6.5 running in VirtualBox within a few hours the system freezes. No screen updates, no network response, no keyboard or mouse response.